# Is there a way to make one Github issue a prerequisite of another?

Tags: github

I'm already familiar that the basic [Github features](https://guides.github.com/features/issues/#notifications) allow referencing between issues/commits/etc. however, this still allows me to close one issue before the prerequisite issue is completed.

I'd like to be able to mark the prerequisite explicitly so that it shows as a blocked issue in the list.

I was expecting this to work from the comments automatically in the same way that you can write **"Fixes #243"** in a commit, but if it is possible I have not discovered how. I've already tried the following comments:

- blocks #...
- blocked by #...
- prerequisite #...
- require(s/ment) #...
- after #...

Is there a way to do what I'm attempting? Or a means other than comments to do the same thing? I haven't spotted anything for it in the UI

Comment: Haven't seen anything like that. Is this even feature of github? maybe look into one of the project management tools with github integration https://github.com/integrations/feature/project-management

Comment: I had no idea i could add plugins so thanks, I'm looking now

Comment: these are all third party tools that use the github api to look at your project.  They are not added in the github interface.

Comment: So https://codetree.com integration is the only option I spotted. At an additional $9 a month though it's a bit expensive so I'm still hoping another way exists

Comment: Sadly still searching for this. By now, we are just adding `PreReq #<ISSUE>` to have it mentioned. A function like this would also help to filter for issues in the backlog, which are waiting for another issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of March 2017, there does not seem to be a way to add prerequisites in Github Issues directly.

The best alternative it to use an integration as suggested by Atreys:

https://github.com/integrations/feature/project-management

Comment: Link is broken as of 2020-June-11

Comment: In 2019, the URL started redirecting to the following URL, so I'm assuming that should be the appropriate place to look nowadays: https://github.com/marketplace/category/project-management